# cakephp show the records from just that id

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a table that has products. In my view page I want to show only the products that belong to that customer. the customer number is in the url at end like /12 or /45 etc
How can I do that. I am very new to cakephp
yhanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [routes](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration) should automatically pass the method this value as `$id`. Especially if you [baked](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1522/Code-Generation-with-Bake) your controllers.

Within this method you could run the [find()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1018/find) method like the following.

```
$customer = $this->Customer->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Customer.id' => $id)));
```

It's difficult providing exact code without knowing more about your app. But check out the links and hopefully that will put you on the path.